# median in each subgroup

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file having city name and price. Need to find the median of price for each group of city.

Input: from a csv file

```
London, 10
London, 25
London, 30
Brasov, 50
Brasov, 60
```

Expected:

```
London, 25
Brasov, 55
```

Solution using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

costs = []
with open("path","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        costs.append(line.split(","))

# with above , data looks like below. We can store in any format.
#costs = [["London",10] , ["London",25], ["London",30],
#         ["Brasov",50], ["Brasov",60]]

df = pd.DataFrame(costs,columns=["city","price"])

res = df.groupby("city")["price"].median() 
print(res)
```

I have tried using Pandas above and works fine. Is there any other approach in Python without using Pandas? I'm trying to tweak below approach to get results per each city group, but could not find a way to fit to groups. Please advice.

```
mid = len(data) // 2

if len(data) % 2 != 0:  # if odd number
    return data[mid]
else:                   # if even number
    return (data[mid] + data [mid-1]) / 2
```

Comment: When you read the csv file try to save the data in a dictionary with key the city and value the array of all values for that city.

After that loop over keys, sort the array and apply your median function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```py
path = 'your/path/to/file'
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    data = {}
    for line in f:
        split_line = line.split(",")
        # Check if city is a key already if not initialize it
        if split_line[0] not in data:
            data[split_line[0]] = []
        data[split_line[0]].append(split_line[1])

# Data wourld look like this
# {'city1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'], 'city2': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']}
def median(values: list) -> float:
    values.sort()
    if len(values) % 2 == 0:
        return (values[len(values) // 2] + values[len(values) // 2 - 1]) / 2
    else:
        return values[len(values) // 2]
    
for city, values in data.items():
    print(city, median(values))
```

Hope it´s clear and helpful.